# PHP - cross-application communication

Tags: php, rest, protocols

I have two PHP applications on my server. One of them has RESTAPI which I would like to consume and render in the second application. What is better way then curling the API? Can I somehow ask php-fpm for the data directly or something like that?

Doing curl and making request through the webserver seems wrong.

All this happens on single server - I know it probably doesn't scale well but its small project.

Comment: You'll be fine with curl, it adds separation to your components, what happens if you had to move them to different servers in the future? In addition, You could look into using http://guzzlephp.org/ as your client as well.

Comment: @Scuzzy `guzzle` is not an alternative, since it is build on top of `curl`.

Comment: You could also use sockets for the communication or even shared memory. But I doubt that is a good idea.

Comment: @arkascha "_Guzzle no longer requires cURL in order to send HTTP requests. Guzzle will use the PHP stream wrapper to send HTTP requests if cURL is not installed. Alternatively, you can provide your own HTTP handler used to send requests._"... But I think this question is more about the concept of looping back through local http requests.

Comment: @Scuzzy That is correct, but in my opinion it is not relevant here: the OP asked if there is some alternative to using `cURL`, so an http request. But `guzzle` does not offer such. It will likewise perform a http request and typically use `cURL` in background, since that library is installed in nearly all situations. That is why I treat it as a convenience layoout on top of `cURL`.

Comment: @Scuzzy what would be the advantage of guzzle instead of curl?

Comment: @Krisa it would help to simplify how you construct your requests, also allow your application to function if the cURL extension wasn't available in your hosting environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why use REST if you can access the functions directly?

If everything is on the same server then there is no need for some REST, since it makes a somewhat pointless run through the webserver. 
But if it is already there and you don't care about the overhead (if there's not much traffic going on then it would make sense), then use `file_get_contents` instead of `curl`, it is easier to use, but I doubt it is faster/slower; both are right.

You could also use a second webserver (a second virtualhost) on a different port for internal use. That way things are nicely separated.

(*If everything is on different servers, but a local network, then using sockets would be fastest.* )

Comment: I dont want to call the functions directly because i am not sure how they might change but i am pretty sure that the API wont. 

I never thought about spining up separate virtualhost for internal use, i guess this will be the best solution. I will also try file_get_contents. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*Doing curl and making request through the webserver seems wrong.* - I disagree with that. You can still achieve what you want to achieve using Php CURL, even if it's on the same server.

Comment: Something not being possible and something feeling wrong are some very distinct statements.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem, but i solved it using MySQL to "queue" tasks, and a worker could use any pooling method, or PHP executing a new server side worker.
Since the results were stored in the same database, the PHP pages could load the results, or the status anytime.

Comment: This is possible, but only for tasks that are not time relevant, so where latency does not play a role, since you have to poll the changes from the database.

Comment: Wouldnt that be a big overhead? I mean i could get the data from the database directly but the reason for using API is just to separate things. Duplicating data seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Krisa Using the database to exchange data between applications is _not_ duplicating! In contrary: several applications can share a common database, so the database server acts as communication hub.

Comment: @arkascha i understand that but idea here is to not touch database from the other app. I could mess something up, i like it separate. Also i would have to duplicate the code that processes the data from one app to the other. I thought the original comment was about cashing the api results into differend database and have the other app to get stuff from there. Maybe i misunderstood him. Anyways THX!

Comment: Accessing the database for different apps is _not_ messing up anything, in contrary. You need one central location where applications touch. What that place is, code or database is irrelevant. And actually a database server is _very_ well suited to handle concurrent and diverse requests. Chances are much higher that you mess things up in self written code. A database server offers a very well defined separation. But as earlier mentioned I doubt that is what you are looking for, due to latency reasons.